# Короткие ссылки на магазины приложений

Tags: google-play, ссылки, кроссплатформенность, appstore, microsoft-store

Как создать ссылку (желательно короткую), которая автоматически определяет тип устройства пользователя и отправляет его в нужный Store?

---

**Например**
Наша ссылка — http://exmp.le/12fg , а где-то в коде она содержит ссылки на соответствующие Store (iTunes, Google Play).

Кликнув на неё с **iPhone** я попадаю в iTunes, а если с **Android**-устройств — в Google Play.

Такой вот редирект.

Answer (score 1):

Сталкивались с задачей, опубликовать одну ссылку в соц сети так, чтобы пользователь попал в нужный ему магазин приложений, в зависимости от устройства?

Если, то вам поможет сервис http://onelink.to.

Вставляете ссылки на нужные вам сторы, и получаете универсальный линк. Если пользователь перейдет по ней с iPhone или iPad, то попадёт в App Store, если с устройства на Android, в Google Play и т.д.

Поддерживается 7 разлиных источников, App Store (iPhone), App Store (iPad), Google Play, Microsoft Store, Blackberry Appworld, Amazon Appstore, и отдельная ссылка для остальных .

Очень удобно. Особенно во времена, когда у нас множество кроссплатформенных приложений. И еще умеет QR код, красота.

Comment: к сожалению не есть ссылку на google play((